# How to roll back to previous commit

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am using VSTS for my MVC project that uses Web Core API.
I made a release that generated an unexpected error that I have been unable to fix (see [How to debug startup in Web Core API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602503/how-to-debug-startup-in-web-core-api/50619439#50619439)).
However I need to quickly move on. I can still deploy from previous builds, so I want to rollback my changes to a previous commit. I have the commit Id that I want to rollback to, so the question is how?

Comment: git checkout <the-revision-id>

Comment: Have you tried searching for "vsts revert to previous commit". This is the first hit, and it looks like this is what you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/undo?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I found the reset command on this link does the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reset command on this link (thanks to Yan Sklyarenko) does what I want;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/undo?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I am not allowed to do that until tomorrow, SO rules for answering your own question.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout <the-rev-id>
```

You will be left on *detached HEAD* state.

If you want your branch to "forget" about newer revisions after the revision you are talking about, then this should suffice:

```
git reset --hard <the-rev-id>
```

Comment: How do I do this in VSTS?

Comment: Visual studio? No idea. I stay at least 10 feet away from Microsoft stuff. If you are in extreme need, just install git and use the operation I'm saying. VS _should_ be able to see what happened.